# Xcode Table View sections without using TableViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a special thing to realize here.

I have a ViewController with a View on it. On the View I have an `ImageView` (I need a nice Background-Image) and many Buttons and Textfields and so on.

Now I need a Tableview. This Table view is located in the center of the screen.
I need sections in this tableview, so when I edit it to have sections its complaining,
because he wants a `TableViewController` to use static cells and sections.

Here's the problem. I cant use a `TableViewController` cause I need this stuff around
the tableview (those buttons and textfields) and I also need the image in the background.

So how can I realize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Builder doesn't allow static cells in a table view that's embedded in a view controller.  You need to have the table view's datasource point to your UIViewController. The view controller should hardcode the values/configuration for the cells.  It's essentially the same thing... you just don't see the results until you run the app.

Also see this question [Using static cells in a storyboard UIView with Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825546/using-static-cells-in-a-storyboard-uiview-with-xcode-4-2)